# Terraform IAM Policy creation - MalformedPolicyDocument: The policy failed legacy parsing

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I have the **Terraform** code (below) that is suppose to create an IAM policy. However, on `terraform apply`, I get the error:

```
Error: creating IAM Policy autoscale-policy: MalformedPolicyDocument: The policy failed legacy parsing
```

**Terraform code:**

```
terraform {
    required_providers {
        aws = {
            source  = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = "~> 4.52.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
    region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "autoscale_policy" {
    name        = "autoscale-policy"
    description = "EBS Autoscaling Policy"
    policy = <<EOT
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
            "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
            "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "ec2:DeleteVolume",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
}
EOT
}
```

However, when I use the AWS cli with the *exact same policy*, the policy is created in AWS with no issue:

```
    --policy-name TestPolicy \
    --policy-document \
'{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Action": [
        "ec2:AttachVolume",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
        "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
        "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
        "ec2:CreateVolume",
        "ec2:DeleteVolume",
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:CreateGrant",
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
    ],
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
  }
}'
```

Does anyone see where there might be a difference between the TF code and the CLI command? **How come my TF code returns a `MalformedPolicyDocument` error when the policy works fine from the cli?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement should be an array.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "autoscale_policy" {
  name        = "autoscale-policy"
  description = "EBS Autoscaling Policy"
  policy      = <<EOT
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
        "Action": [
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
            "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
            "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
            "ec2:CreateVolume",
            "ec2:DeleteVolume",
            "ec2:CreateTags",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:DescribeKey"
        ],
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }]
}
EOT
}
```

> tested it works

OR you can use `data` resource to define your policies.

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "autoscale_policy" {
  name        = "autoscale-policy"
  description = "EBS Autoscaling Policy"
  policy      = data.aws_iam_policy_document.example.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "example" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "ec2:AttachVolume",
      "ec2:DescribeVolumeStatus",
      "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
      "ec2:ModifyInstanceAttribute",
      "ec2:DescribeVolumeAttribute",
      "ec2:CreateVolume",
      "ec2:DeleteVolume",
      "ec2:CreateTags",
      "kms:Decrypt",
      "kms:CreateGrant",
      "kms:Encrypt",
      "kms:ReEncrypt*",
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:DescribeKey"
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
    effect    = "Allow"
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, nice find. I learned something here. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug in the AWS provider: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22879